# How do I specify a message when calling abort() in C?

Tags: c, macos, abort

I tried to open Minecraft in a really old version of MacOS. Every time it opens it says *Minecraft Launcher quit unexpectedly* along with a custom message at the bottom.

```
Exception Type: SIGABRT  
Exception Code: 0x000000000000 0x000000000000  
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:  
abort() called  
Minecraft requires at least MacOS 10.9, and trying to run on 10.8.5
```

How can I do the same thing in my code? If I call `abort()`, how can I specify a reason to display under *Application Specific Information* in the *Application Quit Unexpectedly* window?

Comment: @Barmar U sure? Minecraft Launcher did it, Idk what the Launcher is written in, but if I can do it in whatever the Launcher is written in, I can probably do it in C.

Comment: This isn't part of the functionality of `abort()` in standard C. The "exception note" seems to be something specific to MacOS (and maybe to specific languages), so you should tag accordingly.

Comment: @machine_1 Nope, I'm just using Minecraft as an example of an application that does something I want to know how to do.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but try `assert(! "custom crash message here");`

Comment: https://www.allocinit.net/blog/2008/01/04/application-specific-information-in-leopard-crash-reports/ looks relevant, but says that it's undocumented.

Comment: If you have the source you could alter it. If not, you really can't.

Comment: I don't know why so many people are saying that this thing ***which another program is already doing*** is not possible. Obviously it is possible because another program is doing it! It's Mac-specific, of course.

Comment: https://alastairs-place.net/blog/2013/01/10/interesting-os-x-crash-report-tidbits/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify an error message (or any message) with abort. The abort function only ends the program (similar to the exit function).

Printing to standard error or using the assert statement before the abort call would be a good way of achieving this functionality.

Comment: Does not answer the question. Clearly Minecraft does this so it is possible somehow. It may involve calling another function, for example. And the message is written *after* "abort() called". Note this is a Mac-specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify any message with `abort()` function call. See the ANSIC standard definition and description of the function abort. And you will get the answer.
Write any string message you want to `stdout` or to `stderr` before the `abort()` call.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void abort(void);
```

> The `abort` function causes  **abnormal  program  termination**  to
> occur,  unless  the  signal `SIGABRT` is being caught and the signal
> handler does not return.  Whether open streams with unwritten buffered
> data are flushed, open streams are closed, or temporary files are
> removed  is  implementation-defined.   An  implementation-defined
> form  of  the  status unsuccessful  terminationis  returned  to  the
> host  environment  by  means  of  the  function call raise(SIGABRT).
> The abort function does not return to its caller

Comment: Does not answer the question. Clearly Minecraft does this so it is possible somehow. It may involve calling another function, for example. And the message is written *after* "abort() called". Note this is a Mac-specific question.